# Coletar dados do Usuario Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

Tenho o seguinte código para logar no Facebook:

```
 final FacebookCallback facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Complete!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            executeGraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Facebook Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Facebook error: "+error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };



    login_button = LoginButton.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.login_button));
    login_button.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);
```

Quando o callBack é retornado, através do ID do usuário tento pegar as informações como nome, email e a foto usando o `GraphRequest`:

```
private void executeGraphRequest(final String userId){
    GraphRequest request =new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), userId, null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            Log.i("FACEBOOK", response.getJSONObject().toString());
            Log.i("FACEBOOK", Profile.getCurrentProfile().toString());
        }
    });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, birthday");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Mas as únicas informações que ele retorna é o `name`, `id` e `gender`:

> I/FACEBOOK: {"id":"0000000000","name":"Thiago
>   Domacoski","gender":"male"}

Como faço para pegar o email do usuário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que voce precisa colocar email aqui:

```
login_button.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
```

Assim:

```
login_button.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email);
```

Também é bom verificar no site do facebook, se a permissão de email ta liberada(deve ser automatica mas melhor ver).

Comment: Então, o Facebook só libera o email se o usuário confirmou o mesmo!